# How to fix outOfMemoryException?

Tags: java, websphere

There is a java application on Spring + WebSphere 8.5.5.13

I have instance of this application on dev servers with WebSphere and on remote pre-production server without data.

So, when admins restarts pre-prod server - there is `OutOfMemoryException` error.
But on dev-servers there is no such problem.

- Do you have algorithm to fix issues like this?
- Is increasing jvm size is resolve this issue?
- How to increase jvm size for applications on was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `OutOfMemoryError` (not `OutOfMemoryException`) when you exceed the heap size:

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector

If you have this error on the dev environment and not in the pre production environment I can imagine that is due to the data not the memory allocated to the JVM.

Most common problems related to OutOfMemoryError can be:

- **Cached data**: if you cache objects it is possible that the cached data in dev are smaller than in the pre production environment
- **File load**: check if you load files. It is possible that the size of files is bigger in pre production
- **Database load**: if you load data from a database the number of records can be too much in pre production to hold all of them in memory. In this case you need pagination
- **Algorithm problem**: For example you can create a path to connect to nodes in a graph, but if the algorithm is not well done it is possible that the path in infinite. In dev it can work because you have different data.

Answer (score 1):

`OutOfMemoryException` can be caused by few different things:

- insufficient heap memory
- lack of continuous memory for a large object caused by heap fragmentation
- GC not freeing up the memory fast enough e.g. due to constant allocation if the message reads `GC overhead limit exceeded`
- insufficient file descriptors if the message reads `Unable to create new native thread`

Assuming the application and data is identical than your DEV and PRE-PROD envioronment are configured differently. This is the root cause and should be fixed since developers can't reproduce the problem on DEV.

Comment: Generally a pre prod should be with higher limits than a dev environment, so it is difficult to imagine that the problems are related to the configuration, but this is a personal opinion. Can the questionner confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown when enough space is not available to allocate object in heap memory. Here the garbage collector cannot free enough space for new object allocation and heap memory is fixed and cant be expanded. This error can be thrown when most of time is spent on garbage collection and very less memory is freed, and also when there is insufficient memory to load java class and also even.

You have to look into the stacktrace printed when java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown, as said there might be many causes for this. Below are few,

Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: request size bytes for reason. Out of swap space?
Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: reason stack_trace_with_native_method

Based on the error we can tune JVM settings accordingly. Increasing JVM might always not resolve the issue, as there could be other issues like memory leaks.